# Angular Bootstrap Modal popup does not resize (large)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

**AJS**

```
$scope.WizardModal = $modal.open({
                                templateUrl: 'Wizard.html',
                                size: 'lg',
                                scope: $scope,
                            });
```

**HTML**

[image]

You can see that where it does not inject the 'modal-lg' into html code.Why's that ?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: is modal appear ..??

Comment: @squiroid Yes.Modal popup is working fine.Only the problem is where it doesn't resize.

Comment: Make sure you use latest version of bootstrap ui.

Comment: @dfsq I do have BST 3.1.1.But you can see that where Ajs doesn't inject the 'modal-lg' into html.That's why it doesn't resize.Do you have any clue ?

Comment: What version of angular UI are you using?

Comment: One more time: the problem is likely your Angular UI version. Not bootstrap, not Angular.

Comment: @dfsq Yes.You're perfectly right.I have updated it into V 0.12.0.Now it's working fine.Can you put it as an answer ? Then I can close this thread.Thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier versions of AngularUI didn't implement `size` configuration setting. It was added in Angular UI version 0.12.0 (see [commit](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/976f6083e8485333612b05c023a3c490404543f0)). Updating to this version should bring support to modal window sizes.

```
$scope.WizardModal = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'Wizard.html',
    size: 'lg',
    scope: $scope,
});
```

Link to [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).